# Meaningful tagging with tag wikis full of meaning

Tags: discussion, tags

We're at the beginning of a hopefully long, long journey. Right now, a handful of tags have been created. I'd like to ask everyone to **please edit the tag wiki** (excerpt) so that there are some guidelines about when to apply them. This way we will have a discussion basis, if (or when) we need to merge, or split tags. Tags are one of the big pillars of the SE system, if we start strong, we'll have a better stand in the long run. It'll make the transition into open beta a lot easier (hopefully).

Tags won't be set in stone, they can be quite fluid, even after graduation, but getting a head start will be good.

Comment: I just realised that we probably won't have the necessary people to approve the tag edits yet, so maybe this will take some time...

Comment: There is a chat room for tags, check it out. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107328/tags