# New diffraction, electron-diffraction and transport tags, were these the best choices?

Tags: discussion, tags

Since [Tagging really is important and we need to focus more on it](https://materials.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/201) I thought I'd ask the following.

I've created a few tags for my first two questions and not sure if they are the best options:

- to [How to simulate atomic scattering from solid walls at finite temperature for a particles in a box simulation?](https://materials.stackexchange.com/q/528/201) I've added [transport](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transport) but wondered if it should be something more specific like *thermal-transport* or more general like *transport-mechanisms* or perhaps a mashup of the two: *thermal-transport-mechanisms*
- to [Overview of how self-consistent dynamical low-energy electron diffraction simulations are performed](https://materials.stackexchange.com/q/527/201) I've added [electron-diffraction](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electron-diffraction) and [diffraction](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diffraction)

In none of these cases was I confident that they are the best choices for new tags,

Answer (score 3):

I am happy to see you participating, and to see you genuinely making your best possible effort to keep the tagging system as close to optimal as possible!

It's hard to tell *a priori* how new tag names will be received. I predict that a lot of people will use [transport](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transport) and [electron-diffraction](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electron-diffraction). Not all diffraction is electron diffraction, so I can see the logic behind [diffraction](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diffraction). Thermal-transport might be too specific (but I do not know yet so we might have to wait!). Certainly electron-transport and quantum-transport and exciton-transport are all excellent topics, and it might be better to have them all fit under one [transport](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transport) tag rather than having several.

In the spirit of keeping the number of tags low, maybe we only need one of the diffraction ones (and [electron-diffraction](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electron-diffraction) is a strict subset of [diffraction](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diffraction)), however if others don't mind, I wouldn't mind keeping them for now and seeing how they are used. We still don't have many users, so it's hard to tell. We could visit this if we observe that 100% of the 50 questions on diffraction all end up being about electron-diffraction, or of 5 different types of diffraction get 10 questions each.

I have also added [scattering](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scattering) to your atom scattering question, since I'm sure we'll be getting plenty of scattering questions.

If there's one thing you might be able to help us with, it is perhaps [adding the Wiki for the tags you created](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transport), as we have made sure there is at least *something* for each tag appearing on the first page [of this](https://materials.stackexchange.com/tags).